# Свойство float. Почему не работает padding-left?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется следующее:

```html
<div style="float: left; background-color: #eee;">Блок 1</div>

<div style="background-color: #ccc; padding-left: 20px;">Блок 2</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы содержимое второго блока имело отступ слева, но padding-left по странному стечению обстоятельств не работает. Как исправить и в чем подвох?

Comment: `<div style="background-color: #ccc; padding-left: 20px; float: left;">Блок 2</div>`

Comment: Это обусловлено тем как работает свойство `float`. Когда Вы задаете `float: left;` элемент позиционируется как обычно, а затем вынимается из потока и сдвигается влево. Другие непозиционированные блочные элементы без `float` ведут себя так, как будто элемента с `float` нет, так как он убран из потока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что блочные элементы, не создающие своего потока, игнорируют float'ы - обтекание происходит только у текста.

Добавь `overflow: hidden` чтобы создать поток:

```html
<div style="float: left; background-color: #eee;">Блок 1</div>

<div style="background-color: #ccc; padding-left: 20px; overflow: hidden;">Блок 2</div>
```

или используй `margin` чтобы оттолкнуть текст:

```html
<div style="float: left; background-color: #eee; margin-right: 20px;">Блок 1</div>

<div style="background-color: #ccc;">Блок 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще, через Flex сделать и не мучаться.

```css
.wrap
{width:100%;
display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.blockone
{
background-color: #eee;
display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: baseline;}
.blocktwo
{
background-color: #ccc;
padding-left:20px;
display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="blockone">Блок 1</div>

<div class="blocktwo">Блок 2</div>
</div>
```

А если нужен сдвиг, то заместо `padding-left` используйте `margin-left`

Comment: Да уж... Понаписать столько бессмысленного кода, да ещё и чтобы получилось не то, что требуется...